# Oracle Always Free Cloud Instance (How to correctly setup a cron job)

Tags: python-3.x, cron, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have an always free ubuntu oracle cloud instance on which I am attempting to schedule a python job that can run at a scheduled time using crontab. I installed crontab, started the cron service, and specified the exact cron expression in the crontab using "crontab -e" and editing the file. However, i am not sure why its not working. I ran the script separately and it works fine so its not a problem with the script. The script is executing and then has to send a message to a private Slack workspace. When I execute the script without cron, it is able to do that fine. Is there anything I am missing here?

Here is my cron expression (aka run at 8:53 PM daily)
53 20 * * * python3 ~///scheduled/foo.py

Am I supposed to be doing something else here?

I installed crontab, started the cron service, and specified the exact cron expression in the crontab using "crontab -e" and editing the file. However, i am not sure why its not working. I ran the script separately and it works fine so its not a problem with the script. The script is executing and then has to send a message to a private Slack workspace. When I execute the script without cron, it is able to do that fine.